# What is the equivalent of an EJB 3.0 Session Bean in Spring?

Tags: java, spring, service, ejb-3.0

Is it as simple as creating a POJO with @Transactional methods?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, spring beans are pojos. You have to declare it in `applicationCotnext.xml` or annotate it with `@Service`.

Answer (score 1):

In Spring you create it as normal bean and you specify [session scope](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-session) or `@Scope` annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Spring beans (i.e. properly declared) annotated with `@Transactional` are comparable to **Local** Session Beans. For **Remote** Session Beans, you would have to add some remoting to your Spring  configuration (RMI, Web Services, Hessian, Burlap, HTTP invokers). But Spring remoting does not support out of the box security and transaction propagation (unlike EJBs).

Comment: is this valid? that spring remoting does not support out of the box security and transaction propagation? transaction propagation.. what do you mean? that you can't (for example) persist/merge something to the database?